# Google Analytics shows real time goal hits but they are not reflected on the conversions report after >72 hours

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am trying to send events from my backend to Google Analytics via measurement API. Nodejs code below.

```
const url = 'https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&t=event&tid=' + tid + '&uid=' + uid + '&ec=' + ec + '&ea=' + ea + '&el=' + el+ '&ev=' ev;
const response = await axios.post(url);
```

The uid is a system generated UUID assigned to the user.

In Google Analytics real-time view, I can see the event and conversion reported but the goal values aren't updated in the other reports (waited over 3 days - and in another instance, over a week). I checked the Google Analytics Query Explorer but the events aren't retrieved there either.

I've already verified that the date range is selected correctly on the reports and tried creating another view but to the same effect. It is worth noting that client/browser side events are reported normally on this account/property/view.

Any idea why that might happen please?

Comment: did you turn off bot filtering in the settings for the google analytics account?

Comment: @DalmTo , yes, tried that but didn't make a difference

Comment: Are you using Universal analytics or GA4?

Comment: @DalmTo , I am using Universal Analytics

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending the only `uid` parameter without the `cid` you will be able to see those hits only in your User-ID view (if exists). If you want to see the data in the normal view reports you have to send a **clientId** (`cid`).

Comment: We're trying that now. I will get back to you as soon as we verify if this fixes the issue. Thanks Michele!

Comment: Well, let me know :)

Comment: Moving to CID from UID, the event is still reported in real-time but the conversion isn't anymore even though all fields match. Super weird. Any thoughts?